# How to add fuse filesystems to the mount command?

Tags: mount, automounting, fuse, autofs

I have used linux distributions in the past where the "mount" command could auto-detect the filesystem on a drive and mount it without having to use the "-t" parameter.

Now, I am building my own Linux Distribution that uses busybox and it's built-in "mount" command.

I have installed "exfat-fuse" to be able to mount exFAT partitions.
Running "mount.exfat-fuse /dev/sda1 /tmp/test" works just fine.

How can I make the "normal" mount command work together with this, so that a normal "mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/test" would work? How do other Linux Distributions to this? Will I need to use the full-blown mount command from util-linux to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to enable the CONFIG_FEATURE_MOUNT_HELPERS=y in busybox. Then the mount command will automatically run the external mounter when it can't mount the drive itself.